# PHP scripts has no error but can not see the functionality on joomla 2.5 using jumi

Tags: php, joomla2.5, jumi

Hi I have a several php files which actually is a registration form with validation. So if someone fills up the form correctly, the values will be stored into database. When I am running the file, the form field displays but it has no functionality. I don't know exactly what is the mistake I have made?

The web url is the following if you would like to have a look: [BPHF](http://bphf2012.org/index.php?option=com_jumi&fileid=11)

The files can be seen from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/vof0p4heo4csdn9/dj2NfgcWuE)

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the relevant code here in your question instead of links.

Comment: and leave out your database logins next time ;p

Comment: Check your php error log, it is possible that exceptions are happening behind the scenes, but the form is degrading gracefully.

Comment: I have included `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');` at the beginning of each php file and while running the file, no error is showing. Is it the right way of checking php error log? If not could you please suggest me what shall I do? @MikePurcell

Comment: Your settings look correct. You can check where the errors are being logged (if on linux): `php -i | fgrep -w error_log`. By default they get logged to `syslog (/var/log/messages)`. Wherever the file is, try tailing it `tail -f /var/log/messages` and see if anything is showing up there.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!

After fixing the error, the reason why the functionality isn't working because on the form action location, I have put just register.php. I didn't realize that I have made that silly mistake..